# Recoding factor levels and labels (multiple variables at once) in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe with factors coded with 1 = yes and 2 = no. The factors are all named ending on `_L`. Note that in the real dataframe, they are not all next to each other.

```
df <- data.frame(var_L = factor(c(1,1,1,2,2,2), labels = c("yes","no")),
                 var2_L = factor(c(1,2,1,2,1,2), labels = c("yes","no")),
                 var3_L = factor(c(1,1,2,2,1,2), labels = c("yes","no")))
```

I want to change level/label 1 = yes to 0 = truth and 2 = no to 1 = lie. I want ro recode them by their name, and there are more than 100 variables.

I'm searching for a solution since three days, but I can't find a command to change levels and labels at once and to do it for multiple variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have data similar to this :

```
df <- data.frame(id = 1:3, A_L = c('1 = yes', '2 = no', '1 = yes'), 
                 B_L = c('2 = no', '1 = yes', '1 = yes'))
```

You could use `mutate_at` to apply function to multiple columns and `recode` to change values.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   mutate_at(vars(contains('_L')), 
            ~recode(., '1 = yes' = '0 = truth', '2 = no' = '1 = lie'))

#  id       A_L       B_L
#1  1 0 = truth   1 = lie
#2  2   1 = lie 0 = truth
#3  3 0 = truth 0 = truth
```

Or in base R :

```
cols <- grep('_L', names(df))
df[cols] <- lapply(df[cols], function(x) 
                 ifelse(x == '1 = yes', '0 = truth', '1 = lie'))
```

Comment: The code with mutate at helped a bit. Maybe you know what's wrong with the following code.  
This part (to recode the factors to numeric&change the values) works:  

`df <- df %>%  
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("u_")), ~as.numeric(.)) %>%  
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("u_")), ~recode(., '1' = 1, '2' = 0))`  
  
Then I tried this to recode them into factors again with 0=lie & 1=truth  

`df <- df %>%  
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("u_")), ~as.factor, levels = c(0, 1), labels = c("lie", "truth"))`  
  
and got an error:  

`Column 'u_..._L' is of unsupported type function`

Comment: @Aggi Remove `~` from front. Try : `df <- df %>% mutate_at(vars(starts_with("u_")), factor, levels = c(0, 1), labels = c("lie", "truth"))`

Comment: When I do it as above without the `~` I get the following error: `error in (function (x)  : 
  unused arguments (levels = c(0, 1), labels = c("lie", "truth"))`

Comment: Remember you need to use `factor` and not `as.factor`. `as.factor` does not have `levels` and `labels` argument.

Comment: That works. But now there is still a problem. This is how the code looks now: `df <- df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("u_")),
            ~as.numeric(.)) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("u_")),
            ~recode(., '1' = 1, '2' = 0)) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("u_")),
            factor, levels = c(0, 1), labels = c("lie", "truth"))` 

In the end I have the labels lie and truth, but still the values 1 and 2.

Comment: `factors` are internally represented as integers. See `as.integer(factor(c(3, 4)))`. Also `as.integer(factor(c(30, 40)))` and they will have the value of `labels`, See `factor(c(3, 4), labels = c('Yes', 'No'))`

Answer (score 0):

I can propose you a hack based on `data.table`. There might be a more elegant way to do that but the code is pretty simple. The code could be shorter if I were not creating new columns but I do that to show the logic of the solution

```r
library(data.table)


df <- data.table(solution_L = factor(c(0,1), labels = c("yes","no")),
                 solution2_L = factor(c(0,0), labels = c("yes")))
# df
# solution_L solution2_L
# 1:        yes         yes
# 2:         no         yes
```

You will probably need to convert your dataframe to a `data.table` object, use `setDT` or `as.data.table`. For precaution, since `data.table` updates by reference, you should make a copy of your original dataset

Detect the columns you need to change with `endsWith` (or a regular expression if you prefer):

```r
cols_to_recode <- colnames(df)[endsWith(colnames(df), suffix = "_L")]
```

Here comes the hack. You make a `lapply` to apply over each column

1. A conversion to character
2. Create a new column based on the name that is equal to truth for all observations
3. Replace for observations with "no"

```r
df_modif <- lapply(cols_to_recode,
       function(cname){
         df[, c(cname) := as.character(get(cname))]
         df[,c(paste0(cname,"_r")) := "truth"]
         df[(get(cname) == "no"), c(paste0(cname,"_r")) := "lie"]
       })
df_modif <- df_modif[[length(df_modif)]]
```

The final line is here to make you only keep the last element of the list because you repetitively updated your `data.table`.

Finally, if you preferred the old column names, you can drop the old column :

```r
df_modif[, c(cols_to_recode) := NULL]
# df_modif
# solution_L_r solution2_L_r
# 1:        truth         truth
# 2:          lie         truth
```

and set the names of the recoded variables as the old names

```r
data.table::setnames(df_modif,
                     new = cols_to_recode,
                     old = paste0(cols_to_recode, "_r")
)
# df_modif                     
# solution_L solution2_L
# 1:      truth       truth
# 2:        lie       truth
```

Hope that's clear !